# Proper file globbing in cmake with make and ninja

Tags: cmake

Lots of blogs and talks about CMake tell you *not* to use file globbing to build up your sources. That is, this is bad:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES *.cxx)
```

while this is good:

```
set(SOURCES a.cxx b.cxx c.cxx d.cxx e.cxx [...])
```

My understanding is that the underlying reason for this is that while some build systems support globbing, others don't, and CMake is trying to be build system agnostic in this case. This seems reasonable.

However, in my personal situation, all the build systems I would be using (e.g. make and ninja) *do* support globbing. Is there anyway at all in CMake to forward the globbing along into the build, to get the best of both worlds - the abbreviated globbing that automatically picks up new files without having to rerun CMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake 3.12 added a new argument to [`file(GLOB)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/file.html#glob) that does exactly this:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS *.cxx)
```

> If the CONFIGURE_DEPENDS flag is specified, CMake will add logic to the main build system check target to rerun the flagged GLOB commands at build time. If any of the outputs change, CMake will regenerate the build system.

With the note:

> Note We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate. The CONFIGURE_DEPENDS flag may not work reliably on all generators, or if a new generator is added in the future that cannot support it, projects using it will be stuck. Even if CONFIGURE_DEPENDS works reliably, there is still a cost to perform the check on every rebuild.

But with those caveats, the functionality is there.

Answer (score 4):

> My understanding is that the underlying reason for this is that while some build systems support globbing, others don't, and CMake is trying to be build system agnostic in this case.

The primary reason is stated in the [manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/file.html#command:file):

> **Note:** We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a
>   source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know
>   when to ask CMake to regenerate.

And this is true. If you add a new source file, you need to rerun CMake. So the approach of listing source files manually is recommended because you cannot forget to do so; while forgetting to rerun CMake can lead to frustration. There are IDE's which do this automatically for you if they have CMake integration.

> However, in my personal situation, all the build systems I would be using (e.g. make and ninja) do support globbing. Is there anyway at all in CMake to forward the globbing along into the build, to get the best of both worlds - the abbreviated globbing that automatically picks up new files without having to rerun CMake?

No, there isn't. If there was, IDE's/plugins wouldn't need to implement this functionality. So you need to look in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to make a variable to add source files like you showed.

You should use target_sources instead.

```
target_sources(foobar PRIVATE
    main.cpp
    ...
)
```

The other nice thing about target_sources for 3.13+ users is how you can use it.

Craig Scott wrote a nice article on it:

https://crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources/

=========================

However, CMake 3.12 added a new argument to file(GLOB) that does exactly this:

file(GLOB SOURCES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS *.cxx)

Regarding CONFIGURE_DEPENDS I would see this cmake discourse:
https://discourse.cmake.org/t/is-glob-still-considered-harmful-with-configure-depends/808

From Ben Boerkel (CMake Developer):

"The check costs depend on the platform (and probably generator too). I don’t know of the performance costs, but that’s because I personally find that even if it were performant, there’s at least one issue that I run into often enough to make it not worth it.

I still highly discourage globbing for the reason that files may appear in your source tree that you do not intend to build. The main case I’ve run into is that during conflict resolution in git, the other versions of the file(s) in conflict are named ${base}*${origin}*${pid}.${ext}, so if you try to build in the middle of a conflict, you’re going to glob up these files.

Another reason is that now the addition/removal of a file is not present in your build system diff, so tracking down “what did you change?” in debugging reported problems can be harder since there’s no evidence of accidentally added/removed files in a normal ${vcs} diff output."

==============================

Comment: For what it's worth, I disagree very strongly with that. The argument doesn't even make sense (if you're globbing *.cxx, it's pretty trivial to rename a file you don't want to build to not match the glob, so how is that a motivating argument for avoiding globbing. Also I can see files removed from my normal diff, I don't need _additional_ diff to see them). The time wasted figuring out why your new file isn't being built is so much larger than any alleged cost of globbing.

Comment: Hmm. I don't mind manually adding the source files. But I'll try out your approach for a while and see what I think.